# Ubuntu stuck Copying large files from internal hard disk to external

Tags: files, copy

When ever I try to copy large files from internal hard disk to external the copy will just start fine but then it will stuck at some point. Last night I tried copying 45GB file to my USB 3 harddisk and left it overnight for about 9 hours. When I wake up it's stuck at 18GB. I am using a 4th Generation core i7 Lenovo laptop with 16GB of ram. I am starting to get  worried that I will not be able to get my file back. I have never seen this problem on Windows in my life. 
Anyway is there a way to fix this?

Edit: I tried it with 4 files which are 1.3GB in total, it didn't finish in 1 hour. And this is the first time this is happening to me.

File system: NTFS
Capacity: 1TB

Comment: What is the size of the external, then you could create an archive and then move it?

Comment: what file system is used on the external? 45GB is a pretty large file.

Comment: Each file system has a limit to the size of file it can contain. You should include in your answer the type of file system.

Comment: The filesystem is NTFS, and the storage of the external drive is 1TB.

Comment: I even formatted the HDD with ext4, the same result.

Comment: sort of a long standing bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1208993 . If you read the comments it affects command line not just nautilus.

Comment: found a solution?